# Cross-Platform Game Development between Android and PC?

Tags: android, .net, opengl, opengl-es, xamarin.android

I was hoping to utilize MonoDroid from Xamarin and build a very simple 2D platformer that could run on both Android and the PC.

Coming from PC, I know that certain libraries are better than others when it comes to rendering and certain patterns are important to follow.  For example, we can have libSDL make hardware-accelerated graphics by passing in a simple flag and building resources as such.  In OpenGL, you're basically always hardware accelerated for the most part.

In Android, it looks like we have a basic 2D rendering that is done in software (prior to v. 4.0/ICS) and 3D that is done in hardware.  Does anyone have any experience or bottlenecks/benchmarks for performance?  I'm shooting to deploy to the Ouya or other Android computers eventually (which should be on v.4.0 and be pretty strong) -- I'm just curious what the best way to go about building a game for Android is.

I'm thinking lots of screen refreshing and all that -- basically something that would be similar to what we've come to expect with PC gaming.  I figure if I go the OpenGL / ES route, that lets me port my systems a LOT easier between the two, just building an Ortho viewport -- but what kind of performance can one expect to get in streaming data to the GPU?  I realize this is highly dependent on device (as it is with graphics cards), but if anyone has access to some benchmarks that give me a trend of general idea (i.e. G1 =  polygons; Galaxy S1 =  polygons; S2 =  polygons; etc).

Comment: you can also ask this question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, [Mono Game](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) is a worthwhile thing to try.

`MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4 Framework to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows & Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux and Windows 8 Metro`

And it uses OpenGL for hardware-accelerated rendering on platforms that support it (which is most of them).

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that Android is kinda borked (no 3D and no controller support).  I've written stuff with OpenGL, SDL, and haven't worked much with XNA or Direct X.

Is there a steep learning curve for XNA?  When I looked at it initially (had access to MS's beta pre-v.1 releases) it was still very... ugly and weak.

Comment: I think learning XNA doesn't hurt, especially when you want to write game cross platform.  You can get starting with this link: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials. Also, I think performance does depend on device.If you think it isn't enough for you, http://www.mosync.com/ is another option, it is a C/C++ framework cross platform.

Comment: Mono Game is open source but for development in Android we required "Mono for Android" which is paid. Correct me if there is another solution which is free :)

Answer (score 2):

performance does depend on device.

you can read about opengl benchmarks on popular android apps to see what is their status.

in any case , if you wish to have an openGL solution that works on both PC and android , consider using LibGdx